# Docker Desktop pull fail with "unexpected eof"

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I´m facing the Problem that I can´t pull some Docker images and `docker login` also works just sometimes.
This occurs only under Windows 10 Pro. I also tested it under Linux and it worked with default configuration.
I´ve already searched for the solution here, but my network connection isn´t the problem, since Linux works on the same network and I also don´t use any Proxy Server which I have to configure.

I´m trying to execute `docker pull postgres`. The output is:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/postgres/manifests/latest: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?account=unkownuser&scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fpostgres%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: unexpected EOF
```

Other images fail also with the same error and sometimes even the docker login fails with the `unexpected EOF` error.

Everything worked fine since the last update.
I´ve already downgraded my version, but it didn´t help. I also tried to switch from windows to linux containers, no effect.

Does anybody else have this problem or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Any help here https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6192?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy yes the Router was my Problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use a FritzBox?
If yes try the following it helped me:

1. Log into your FritzBox
2. In the bottom left Corner is a Button called Content (I assume its called that. I got the German version which says "Inhalt")
3. Click "FRITZ!Box Support"
4. Disable Hardware acceleration